# Using the Gdiplus outside of the main

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm writting a saimple C++ program to just display an `BMP` image on the screen using the `Gdiplus`. There is one thing that really makes me wonder. When I move the `Gdiplus` initialization code from the `WinMain` to my `OnPaint` `WM_PAINT` handler function like that:

```
void OnPaint(HDC hdc) {

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image theImg(L"C:/....bmp");
    //graphics.DrawImage(&theImg, 0, 0)

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

I'm getting the `access violation` exception. When the initialization code lies in the `WinMain` function and in the `OnPaint` there is only the

```
void OnPaint(HDC hdc) {
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image theImg(L"C:/....bmp");
    //graphics.DrawImage(&theImg, 0, 0)
}
```

code everything is working.

My question is WHY moving the initialization code to the handler function makes the problem?

Comment: How many times are you going to initialize the library?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Of cause ALWAYS once! As I've written when I move the initialization to the handler I don't have an initialization in the WinMain!

Comment: You do realize that code has a flow to it.  How many times will `OnPaint` be called?  Yes, visually you only have a single line of code, but logically and during the program flow, how many times is the initialization code called?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, You're right - the handler could be called multiple times BUT does it really make a difference since every single time I'm shutting down the API (calling the `GdiplusShutdown`)?